# How to add custom add-ins in Excel 2016 without browsing it?

Tags: excel, add-in, excel-2016

In Excel 2011 I used to paste my custom Add-In in 'Applications>Microsoft Office 2011>Office>Add-Ins' location. I don't want to browser it from 'Tools' menu item. So kindly help me on this. I am kind of stuck with this. I need a similar location in 'Applications>Microsoft Excel' where I can add my Add-Ins.

Your help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

paste it into C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns

change user to your user